# CMake Error - trying to install chromaprint

Tags: linux, centos

I am trying to install chromaprint and I am getting from CMake Error.

I can't figure out how to fix it.

Error:

```
root@matrix [~/chromaprint-0.6]# cmake -DWITH_FFTW3=ON .
-- Using FFTW3 for FFT calculations
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
FFMPEG_LIBAVCODEC_INCLUDE_DIRS
   used as include directory in directory /root/chromaprint-0.6/examples
FFMPEG_LIBAVCODEC_LIBRARIES
    linked by target "fpcalc" in directory /root/chromaprint-0.6/examples
FFMPEG_LIBAVFORMAT_INCLUDE_DIRS
   used as include directory in directory /root/chromaprint-0.6/examples
FFMPEG_LIBAVFORMAT_LIBRARIES
    linked by target "fpcalc" in directory /root/chromaprint-0.6/examples
FFMPEG_LIBAVUTIL_INCLUDE_DIRS
   used as include directory in directory /root/chromaprint-0.6/examples
FFMPEG_LIBAVUTIL_LIBRARIES
    linked by target "fpcalc" in directory /root/chromaprint-0.6/examples

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
root@matrix [~/chromaprint-0.6]#
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install `ffmpeg-devel`:

```
# rpm -qa | grep ffmpeg
ffmpeg-libpostproc-0.6.5-1.el5.rf
ffmpeg-devel-0.6.5-1.el5.rf
ffmpeg-0.6.5-1.el5.rf
```

and try again:

```
# cmake -DWITH_FFTW3=ON .
-- Using FFTW3 for FFT calculations
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /usr/local/src/chromaprint-0.6
```